# Block access between namespaces but allow access for external traffic

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have two namespaces: `prod` and `default`.
I want to disable access for resources inside these namespaces (resources from `default` NS can't get access for resources from `prod`, and resources from `prod` can't get access for resources from `default`)
BUT allow the opportunity to access these resources for external traffic (ingresses).

```
# namespaces.yaml

---
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prod
  labels:
    tier: prod

---
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: default
  labels:
    tier: infra
```

```
# network-policies.yaml

---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: network
  namespace: prod
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: network
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            tier: dev
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            tier: rc
```

```
# services.yaml

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "conference.appService" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "conference.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: {{ include "conference.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    role: app
```

Pods from `prod` have access to the other pods inside given namespace.
Pods from `default` don't have access to the pods inside `prod`.

When I try to get access to the service from the browser it's blocked.
When I try to use port-forwarding to the service inside `prod` - all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in from part in network policy.

```
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: network
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
      - podSelector: {}
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            tier: dev
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            tier: rc
  egress:
    - {}
```

The main idea of this selectors it:
`podSelector` - for selecting the pods IN CURRENT namespace
`namespaceSelector` - for selecting the namespaces
`namespaceSelector.podSelector` - for selecting pods inside given namespace

and my problem:

`ipBlock` - for selecting EXTERNAL IP addresses

it's doesn't work for internal IPs so in my case `0.0.0.0/0` will be OK.
`except` will not disallow internal traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Define default deny network policy to deny all ingress type traffic.

Deploy another namespace called ingress

Deploy ingress controller in ingress namespace

Then define network policy to allow access from ingress namespace to prod and another one to allow access from ingres to default. You should be able to access both prod and default externally via ingress controller